# C++/CLI compiler fails to recognize implementation of generic method returning IEnumerable<U>^

Tags: .net, generics, c++-cli

I'm trying to implement a generic method < U >, on my implementation of a generic interface < T >, and the compiler will not accept my implementation method if I'm returning IEnumerable < U >.

Here's a small code snippet that fully illustrates the problem:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

generic <typename T> public interface class IBase
{
    generic <typename U> U GetOne(T input);
    generic <typename U> IEnumerable<U>^ GetMany(T input);
};

public ref class Derived : public IBase<String^>
{
    public:
        generic <typename U> virtual U GetOne(String^ input); // WORKS!
        generic <typename U> virtual IEnumerable<U>^ GetMany(String^ input); //FAILS!
};
```

The error I get from the VS2015 (SP3) compiler is:

> Error C2553   'System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable< U >
>   ^Derived::GetMany(System::String ^)': overriding virtual function
>   return type differs from 'System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable< U >
>   ^IBase::GetMany(System::String ^)'

As you can see from the message, the return type it's complaining about is identical to what it claims to expect. It's as if it doesn't realize the `U` in the return type is the same as the `U` in the generic definition.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Or is this perhaps a known issue with the compiler? If so, is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Honestly in this case I think it's a compiler bug. If base is an abstract ref class then even GetOne() doesn't work. I can't even make it an explicit implementation :|

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Thanks for taking the time to look into it. I was suspecting the same thing, but wanted to rule out a silly mistake on my side. I've tried every permutation of explicit impl, defining the base in C#, deriving from a dummy interface from IBase<String^>. Nothing flies. Any possible workarounds you can think of? :(

Comment: Nothing I'd like to see in my own code :( Maybe dropping the generic implementation in favor of `IEnumerable<Object^>^ GetMany(T input);`. If you will work with a base `ref class` (not an `interface class`) it may be explicitly implemented in a private method with an _helper_ public methods to reintroduce the generic. Unfortunately in C++/CLI we don't even have extension methods...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Thanks for the suggestions. I thought about the `Object^` possibility - the trouble is, in reality I wanted to go even further and use a type with an interface constraint for `U`. But given I can't even get the simple case to compile, that's out of the window! And sadly, the base has to be an interface as it's part of a dynamically loaded plugin, where the interface will in the end be declared in a C# assembly. :(

Comment: @Dan: Thanks for checking... looks like it's not a bug that's considered high priority. Doesn't seem like a very extreme use-case to me though! :(

Comment: @Dan: Hmm.. I just tried that. The intellisense stops complaining, but the compiler still gives a return type mismatch! Does it compile for you on 2017RC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I could get working in C++/CLI is to move the generic parameter `U` to the class instead of placing it on each method:

```
generic <typename T, typename U> public interface class IBase
{
    virtual U GetOne(T input);
    virtual IEnumerable<U>^ GetMany(T input);
};
```

this may not be possible with your actual code (i.e., somebody else provides `IBase` and you can't change it.)

With that change, you can implement the interface:

```
generic<typename U>
public ref struct Derived : public IBase<String^, U>
{
    virtual U GetOne(String^);
    virtual IEnumerable<U>^ GetMany(String^ input);
};
```